# How linux default applications work without Pthread installed?

Tags: linux, pthreads

I have noticed a few times that libpthread is not installed by default on some fresh linux installs, like we see on a newly launched AWS machine. My question is: How the programs that come with linux work without libpthread installed? Is it because they statically link while compiling those programs? Or is it because they don't use libpthread at all? Or is it because libpthread IS a static library (sorry if I sound dumb)?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

As you say. Or it have code of pthread in itself (static linking), or they dont need that lib to work .